# Command to script database structure and data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Every time I want to create a script of the database structure (and data) of our deployment database (a brand new database with the software's basic data), I have go to SSMS, select the database, Tasks -> Scripts -> Generate Scripts. Then I have a very specific setting which I have to change every single time to the same values.

This is very time consuming and looks like a task that could very well be automated. Is it possible to automate this task from within SSMS, with my specific settings? If not, is there a way to automate it outside SSMS? I do not discard writing a C# console program to perform that, this task is not for the final user it's for our labs.

**UPDATE**

The objective here, as usual, is getting the solution which will take less time. So, before I got to the C# coding level, I would like to try automating the existing tools. The order would be:

1. Can I automate from SSMS?
2. Can I automate by running a outside script?
3. How can I automate with C# coding? (the learning resources were pointed out by Nicholas Carey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you using the script for? (I can think of backup, release versioning, source control for logging each change)

- backup -> could be done by keeping a database backup
- release versioning -> perhaps use SMO as suggested, you'd have control of what gets scripted and in what order
- source control -> for the time it would take to develop/test/refine, Red Gate's
  http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/
  might be a better answer

Comment: The general objective is both release versioning and source control, but I already manage to do it using SVN. This is our deployment database, so it contains the structure and the basic data to get started. The only thing is that I would like to automate the processes. I just thought there might be a way to save my settings. I lose 2-3 minutes a day on that, so I don't think it's worth writing a C# program using SMO (maybe later). But you gave a good overview of the options.

Answer (score 0):

Look at SMO: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169(v=SQL.100).aspx

Then script your database, put the scripts in source control and require that changes be made via scripts.